# Use of postgis with hibernate

Tags: postgis, hibernate-spatial

We have an existing postgis database. Our application is developed in Java, but queries database through a jni dll, which appears to be not very effective for our purpose.

I've managed to migrate to jdbc, and it's working well, but the next step would be to rely on a framework such as hibernate-spatial, which i don't know at all.

How mature is it? I've seen some people here using it, what do you think of it?

It looks that it supports only cartesian coordinates and it may be a concern for us for distance computation.

Comment: what are your goals using postgis and your java app?

Comment: routing and display of vector data on a 3D earth view. Performance is a concern for queries and display, a little less for routing.

Comment: In addition I'd like to know how much hibernate would bring us (for development times, flexibility), or if it is a no go (performance issues, lack of maturity)